# How to get text from entry/text widget generated dynamically on action?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to get data from every newly generated text/entry widget on click:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    tk.Text(frame, height=1, width = 30).grid(row=i+3, column=2, sticky ='w',
                                                        padx = 10, pady = 4)
```

Comment: read here : http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Comment: @Stack StringVar() doesn't support indexing so how i'll assign and retrieve text from entry?

Comment: Any particular reason why you wouldn't add your Entry / Text to an iterable type such as a dictionary?

Comment: How exactly is it evident from the above code snippet that the widgets are created dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a combination of four questions:

1. How to get the string in Entry?
2. How to get the string in Text?
3. How to call a method when a widget is clicked?
4. How to dynamically create widgets?

**How to get the string in Entry?**

```
import tkinter as tk
...
entry = tk.Entry(...)
...
entry.get() # gets the string in an Entry
```

**How to get the string in Text?**

```
import tkinter as tk
...
text = tk.Text(...)
...
text.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
```

**How to call a method when a widget is clicked?**

```
import tkinter as tk
...
def a_method(*args):
    print("Hello")
...
widget = tk.Label(...)
...
widget.bind('<Button-1>', a_method)
```

**How to dynamically create widgets?**

Creating widgets dynamically is no excuse for not assigning them to variables. It is not strictly necessary to assign those particular objects to variables, but I doubt that's what a python programmer would want to deal with.

Create multiple widgets using an iterable type, such as a `dict`:

```
import tkinter as tk
...
a_dict = dict()
my_widget_names = {"Township", "Rebellion", "Know", ...}
for name in my_widget_names:
    a_dict[name] = tk.Button(...)
```

---

Here's an example that has all of the above:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def display_data(d, key):
    if d[key].winfo_class() == 'Text':
        data = d[key].get('1.0', 'end-1c')
    elif d[key].winfo_class() == 'Entry':
        data = d[key].get()
    print(data)


def populate_widgets(widget_class_name, keys):
    global root
    widget_dict = dict()
    if widget_class_name in ('Text', 'Entry'):
        if widget_class_name == 'Text':
            for name in keys:
                widget_dict[name] = tk.Text(root, height=4)
        elif widget_class_name == 'Entry':
            for name in keys:
                widget_dict[name] = tk.Entry(root)
        for name in keys:        
            widget_dict[name].pack()
            widget_dict[name].bind('<Button-1>',
                                        lambda event, d=widget_dict,
                                        key=name: display_data(d, key))
        return widget_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    widget_names = {"Township", "Rebellion", "Know", "Your", "Enemy"}
    my_text_widgets = populate_widgets('Text', widget_names)
    my_entry_widgets = populate_widgets('Entry', widget_names)
    root.mainloop()
```